# Switch Case with Multiple string Input

Tags: javascript

I'm working on having a user input basically multiple strings(letters) and outputting the results based off the content of each of the cases that were put in the input box. 
Example:
I input in the box: HELLO:
outputs: 
Squats
Wall Sits
Wall Sits
Wall Sits
Burpees

Is it possible? 
If not, what are some alternatives.

```js
//Input
function myFunction() {
    var text;
  var output;
 
    var fruits = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    switch(fruits.toUpperCase()) {
        case "A":
              output="Sample Text";
        case "I":
        case "N":
        case "X":
            text = "Jumping Jacks";
        break;
        case "B":
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "Y":
        text = "Crunches";
        break;
        case "C":
        case "H":
        case "T":
        text = "Squats";
        break;
        case "D":
        case "K":
        case "R":
        case "Z":
            text = "Push ups";
        break;
        case "E":
        case "L":
        case "V":
            text = "Wall Sits";
        break;
        case "F":
        case "M":
        case "O":
        case "S":
            text = "Burpees";
        break;
        case "G":
        case "P":
        case "U":
        case "W":
            text = "Arm Circles";
        break;
        default:
        text = "I have never heard of that fruit...";
    }
    document.getElementById("excercise").innerHTML = text;
  
  
  ////////Random Generator for Reps/////////
var myArray = ["60","50", "20", "30", "15", "10"];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.getElementById("reps").innerHTML = randomItem;
  ////////////////////////////////////
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write a letter in the input field and click the button.</p>
<p>The switch statement will execute a block of code based on your input.</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>
  <span id="reps"></span>
  <span id="excercise"></span>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can find my code here https://codepen.io/ebizl/pen/PyrQmZ

Comment: strings are also arrays, so have you tried iterating over them and calling switch for every char in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to switch on every char of the input word:

```
 var text = "";
 for(const char of fruit.toUpperCase()) {
  switch(char) {
    case "A":
       text += "Sample Text";
       break;

    case "I":
    case "N":
    case "X":
        text += "Jumping Jacks";
        break;

    case "B":
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "Y":
      text += "Crunches";
      break;

    case "C":
    case "H":
    case "T":
      text += "Squats";
      break;

    case "D":
    case "K":
    case "R":
    case "Z":
       text += "Push ups";      
       break;

    case "E":
    case "L":
    case "V":
        text += "Wall Sits";
        break;

    case "F":
    case "M":
    case "O":
    case "S":
        text += "Burpees";
        break;

    case "G":
    case "P":
    case "U":
    case "W":
        text += "Arm Circles";
       break;

    default:
       text += "I have never heard of that fruit...";
       break;
  }
  text += "<br />";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Please, could you help me understand the meaning of the text +="\n"

Comment: I had difficulty putting the new strings in a new line. So I put the break line element. Could you explain to me why that works, instead of the "\n" ?

Comment: @ebizl yeah right. The \n is a linebreak encoding used in javascript strings and elsewhere, e.g. `console.log("a\nb")` will log two lines. In HTML however, those linebreaks get parsed (you won't see `\n` in the text) but they get ignored (which I always forget, apologies) therefore you have to add the html linebreaks instead

Answer (score 0):

you want to check the entire input but your code doesn't

here is the steps you should do:

- split the input value to chars
- loop the resulted array from split to check every char and what you want to do with it
- concatenate the result and show it

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way:

```
var fruits = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++)
   console.log(getValue(fruits[i]));

function getValue(c){
var output = "", text = "";
    switch(c.toUpperCase()) {
        case "A":
              output="Sample Text";
        case "I":
        case "N":
        case "X":
            text = "Jumping Jacks";
        break;
        case "B":
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "Y":
        text = "Crunches";
        break;
        case "C":
        case "H":
        case "T":
        text = "Squats";
        break;
        case "D":
        case "K":
        case "R":
        case "Z":
            text = "Push ups";
        break;
        case "E":
        case "L":
        case "V":
            text = "Wall Sits";
        break;
        case "F":
        case "M":
        case "O":
        case "S":
            text = "Burpees";
        break;
        case "G":
        case "P":
        case "U":
        case "W":
            text = "Arm Circles";
        break;
        default:
        text = "I have never heard of that fruit...";
    }
    return {output, text };
}
```